# how to create multiple conditions on same column in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

i am trying to get some data is a specific format.Currently i have the below data in a table:

```
TARGET_NAME      KEY_VALUE                     METRIC_COLUMN  VALUE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
orclDB1_host    orclDB1_host:DBMS_CREDENTIAL    TABLE_NAME  DBMS_CREDENTIAL
orclDB1_host    orclDB1_host:DBMS_DDL           TABLE_NAME  DBMS_DDL
orclDB1_host    orclDB1_host:DBMS_LOB           TABLE_NAME  DBMS_LOB
orclDB1_host    orclDB1_host:DBMS_RANDOM        TABLE_NAME  DBMS_RANDOM
orclDB1_host    orclDB1_host:DBMS_SQL           TABLE_NAME  DBMS_SQL
orclDB1_host    orclDB1_host:DBMS_CREDENTIAL    GRANTEE     PUBLIC
orclDB1_host    orclDB1_host:DBMS_DDL           GRANTEE     PUBLIC
orclDB1_host    orclDB1_host:DBMS_LOB           GRANTEE     PUBLIC
orclDB1_host    orclDB1_host:DBMS_RANDOM        GRANTEE     PUBLIC
orclDB1_host    orclDB1_host:DBMS_SQL           GRANTEE     PUBLIC
orclDB1_host    orclDB1_host:DBMS_CREDENTIAL    PRIVILEGE   EXECUTE
orclDB1_host    orclDB1_host:DBMS_DDL           PRIVILEGE   EXECUTE
orclDB1_host    orclDB1_host:DBMS_LOB           PRIVILEGE   EXECUTE
orclDB1_host    orclDB1_host:DBMS_RANDOM        PRIVILEGE   EXECUTE
orclDB1_host    orclDB1_host:DBMS_SQL           PRIVILEGE   EXECUTE
```

i need the above data in this format:

```
DB_TABLE                        TABLE_NAME         GRANTEE   PRIVILEGE
------------------------------------------ ----------------------------
orclDB1_host:DBMS_CREDENTIAL     DBMS_CREDENTIAL   PUBLIC   EXECUTE
orclDB1_host:DBMS_RANDOM         DBMS_RANDOM       PUBLIC   EXECUTE
orclDB1_host:DBMS_DDL            DBMS_DDL          PUBLIC   EXECUTE
orclDB1_host:DBMS_SQL            DBMS_SQL          PUBLIC   EXECUTE
orclDB1_host:DBMS_LOB            DBMS_LOB          PUBLIC   EXECUTE
```

i tried the below sql,but am only able to get this:

```
select distinct KEY_VALUE as DB_AND_TABLE,VALUE as GRANTEE from mgmt$metric_current 
where metric_name='ME$PUBLICPRIVS' 
and target_name like 'orclDB1_host%' 
and COLUMN_LABEL='GRANTEE'
```

Result:

```
DB_AND_TABLE                 GRANTEE
---------------------------------------
orclDB1_host:DBMS_LOB         PUBLIC
orclDB1_host:DBMS_RANDOM      PUBLIC
orclDB1_host:DBMS_SQL         PUBLIC
orclDB1_host:DBMS_DDL         PUBLIC
orclDB1_host:DBMS_CREDENTIAL  PUBLIC
```

Can you please help.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select KEY_VALUE as DB_AND_TABLE,
       max(case when METRIC_COLUMN = 'TABLE_NAME' then VALUE end) as table_name,
       max(case when METRIC_COLUMN = 'GRANTEE' then VALUE end) as GRANTEE,
       max(case when METRIC_COLUMN = 'PRIVILEGE' then VALUE end) as PRIVILEGE
from mgmt$metric_current 
group by key_value;
```

Comment: how to add a condition like 'PRIVILEGE is not null' in the above sql.

Comment: @vivek . . . You can filter after the fact using:  `max(case when METRIC_COLUMN = 'PRIVILEGE' then VALUE end) is not null` or similar logic.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   mgmt$metric_current
PIVOT (
  MAX( value ) FOR metric_column IN (
    'TABLE_NAME' AS table_name,
    'GRANTEE' AS grantee,
    'PRIVILEGE' AS privilege
  )
)
```

Which, for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mgmt$metric_current ( TARGET_NAME, KEY_VALUE, METRIC_COLUMN, VALUE ) AS
SELECT 'orclDB1_host', 'orclDB1_host:DBMS_CREDENTIAL', 'TABLE_NAME', 'DBMS_CREDENTIAL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'orclDB1_host', 'orclDB1_host:DBMS_DDL',        'TABLE_NAME', 'DBMS_DDL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'orclDB1_host', 'orclDB1_host:DBMS_LOB',        'TABLE_NAME', 'DBMS_LOB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'orclDB1_host', 'orclDB1_host:DBMS_RANDOM',     'TABLE_NAME', 'DBMS_RANDOM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'orclDB1_host', 'orclDB1_host:DBMS_SQL',        'TABLE_NAME', 'DBMS_SQL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'orclDB1_host', 'orclDB1_host:DBMS_CREDENTIAL', 'GRANTEE',    'PUBLIC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'orclDB1_host', 'orclDB1_host:DBMS_DDL',        'GRANTEE',    'PUBLIC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'orclDB1_host', 'orclDB1_host:DBMS_LOB',        'GRANTEE',    'PUBLIC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'orclDB1_host', 'orclDB1_host:DBMS_RANDOM',     'GRANTEE',    'PUBLIC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'orclDB1_host', 'orclDB1_host:DBMS_SQL',        'GRANTEE',    'PUBLIC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'orclDB1_host', 'orclDB1_host:DBMS_CREDENTIAL', 'PRIVILEGE',  'EXECUTE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'orclDB1_host', 'orclDB1_host:DBMS_DDL',        'PRIVILEGE',  'EXECUTE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'orclDB1_host', 'orclDB1_host:DBMS_LOB',        'PRIVILEGE',  'EXECUTE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'orclDB1_host', 'orclDB1_host:DBMS_RANDOM',     'PRIVILEGE',  'EXECUTE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'orclDB1_host', 'orclDB1_host:DBMS_SQL',        'PRIVILEGE',  'EXECUTE' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> TARGET_NAME  | KEY_VALUE                    | TABLE_NAME      | GRANTEE | PRIVILEGE
> :----------- | :--------------------------- | :-------------- | :------ | :--------
> orclDB1_host | orclDB1_host:DBMS_SQL        | DBMS_SQL        | PUBLIC  | EXECUTE  
> orclDB1_host | orclDB1_host:DBMS_DDL        | DBMS_DDL        | PUBLIC  | EXECUTE  
> orclDB1_host | orclDB1_host:DBMS_RANDOM     | DBMS_RANDOM     | PUBLIC  | EXECUTE  
> orclDB1_host | orclDB1_host:DBMS_CREDENTIAL | DBMS_CREDENTIAL | PUBLIC  | EXECUTE  
> orclDB1_host | orclDB1_host:DBMS_LOB        | DBMS_LOB        | PUBLIC  | EXECUTE
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bc220acb6a95dc0c1b1e63fd06bfcbff)*